# How to have 2 different versions of the same program installed in PC?

Tags: windows-xp, vpn

I wish to install two versions of a software application, i.e. and older version and newer version.

The problem is that whenever I try to install an older version a popup appears at initialization that "newer version is already installed".

My question is how to avoid that? Is there any way from the registry editor or any other way?

I tried installing as a different user, but in vain

The setup file is `.msi`

The software = Forticlient, a VPN software that creates virtual network.
OS = Windows XP SP3

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a piece of software such as [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com)

"Sandboxie runs your programs in an isolated space which prevents them from making permanent changes to other programs and data in your computer."

Answer (score -1):

One way that seemed to work for me, on Windows 8 is to change the Internet Explorer install location. So try creating a desktop folder called IE install() and install the old one there and  the newer one in the regular install location. That should work! Another approach if you have a usb and  a second windows computer, install it there and plug in the usb to run Internet explorer.